# How to limit access to domain in VPS, Nginx?

Tags: nginx, domain, vps

I have a debian VPS with Nginx reversed proxy for my website. And forward DNS domain to my VPS. My question is, how to limit access to public for access my website through domain?

For example, i have domain:

```
admin.websitename.com
```

But i want this website is only can access by me and my friend, because this is admin dashboard for login to see all data inside our website.

What method or any tutorial for this? I have already search on Google, but i think my keyword is not correct. Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your and your friend's public IP addresses are static and will not change, which is highly unlikely seeing the price and rarity of IPv4 addresses, you can setup an IP whitelist like with this [guide](https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/how-to-whitelist-ip-in-nginx/)

---

If they are dynamic or you want to access it from outside your home, you can either either

- Use an authentication frontend like [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/), or [Authelia](https://github.com/authelia/authelia) in front of your infra to allow authentication.
- Or create a VPN server and apply the IP Whitelist method above to only allow people connected to the VPN to access it.

The VPN method is the safest since you don't open the site to the outside world, but can be tricky to implement

Comment: Thank you so much for the explain. Is there any tutorial to make VPN Server which is same with this problem? I have searched on google, but, its only tutorial to install.